# How do I solve: The type or namespace Windows does not exist in namespace Microsoft?

Tags: c#

How do I solve this missing dependency? Googling around for this problem, it seems rare. I see similar ones like `The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System'` but nowhere do I see someone explain this particular message.

Log files naturally recorded by windows at locations such as `C:\Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles\BootPerfDiagLogger.etl` record useful forensic security info, such as every process that ran persistently at boot.

My goal is to parse these files into some intermediary structure like XML or JSON so I can import the data to Python.

I wanted to [parse Windows ETL files in Python for forensic / security data science](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUR-L9AtzQE). I thought this would be easy since there's a [Python library for it](https://github.com/airbus-cert/etl-parser) but upon running that library, it doesn't work and is probably no longer maintained.

Luckily I found [a Microsoft dev blog on parsing ETL files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201211-00/?p=104539) with the same classes Windows exposes to allow Windows Performance Analyzer to do it.

The example code shown was like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing;
using Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.Disk;
using Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.Processes;

class FileOperation
{
    public IProcess IssuingProcess;
    public string Operation;
    public string Path;
    public long Size;
    public decimal Duration;
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var etlFileName = args[0];

        var diskTrace = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(etlFileName) + "-disk.csv";
        var fileTrace = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(etlFileName) + "-file.csv";

        using (ITraceProcessor trace = TraceProcessor.Create(etlFileName))
        {
            var pendingDisk = trace.UseDiskIOData();
            var pendingFile = trace.UseFileIOData();

            trace.Process();

            ProcessDisk(pendingDisk.Result, diskTrace);
            ProcessFile(pendingFile.Result, fileTrace);
        }
    }
```

I won't include the `ProcessDisk` and `ProcessFile` classes here because those seem to be geared toward whatever debugging purpose the writer had. Rather, I'm interested in `trace`. Based on the methods I see called: `UseDiskIOData`, `UseFileIOData`, presumably there is a longer list of methods like that I could use to access all available data for each trace.

My immediate goal with this question is just to view what methods exist on the `trace` object.

So I did some research on how you look at all properties on an object in C#, and there are plenty of answers, that's probably not a problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing;
using Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.Disk;
using Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.Processes;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var etlFileName = args[0];

        #var diskTrace = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(etlFileName) + "-disk.csv";
        #var fileTrace = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(etlFileName) + "-file.csv";

        using (ITraceProcessor trace = TraceProcessor.Create(etlFileName))
        {
            Type myType = trace.GetType();
            IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                object propValue = prop.GetValue(trace, null);

                // Do something with propValue
                Console.WriteLine(propValue);
            }
            #var pendingDisk = trace.UseDiskIOData();
            #var pendingFile = trace.UseFileIOData();

            #trace.Process();

            #ProcessDisk(pendingDisk.Result, diskTrace);
            #ProcessFile(pendingFile.Result, fileTrace);
        }
    }
```

But what I did have a problem with is this:

[image]

`The type or namespace Windows does not exist in namespace Microsoft`

As I said, I looked around for solutions to this and found nothing.

Comment: You didn't add link to Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.Processing.dll in your project, or didn't install propper package.

Comment: What kind of project did you create? That’s a Windows Runtime api

Comment: @DanielA.White I created a console application. I should've known I couldn't just copy / paste and compile C# from some blog and have it work. I know nothing about this language.

Comment: Why can't Visual Studio just look up the DLL in the System folder, the way a linker does at run-time?

Comment: That’s not the way .net works

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#modify-a-net-project-to-use-windows-runtime-apis